# Redireccionar varios enlaces a un nuevo enlace .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, web, .htaccess, configuración

quisiera saber si habría una manera de hacer que varios enlaces, se redirecciones a una nueva en .htaccess. Eh probado con lo siguiente.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www1.pagina.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2.pagina.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www3.pagina.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www4.pagina.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www5.pagina.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Pero creo que no es la mejor manera y quisiera saber como podría hacer eso, ya que me esta saliendo error y me dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que te falta `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Ahora todos me redirecciona al nuevo enlace pero me sigue saliendo que redireccionó muchas veces

Comment: No estoy seguro pero probaría quitando el último `OR` anterior a la `RewriteRule`

Comment: Nada, me sigue saliendo que se esta redireccionando muchas veces.

Comment: Podrías tratar de ver qué redirecciones está enviando el server para poder entender el origen del error. Acá hay un plug-in de chrome que supuestamente lo hace más fácil (nunca lo usé) y te muestra a lista de redirecciones. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll?hl=en